# Use Adobe CS4 speech analysis from flash

Tags: flash, flash-cs4, speech-recognition

Adobe premier is able to transcribe spoken words (videos audio track) to text.
Is it possible to use this module from flash or flex? Id like to control a web-application by spoken words (using a webcams mic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Flash CS4 and Premiere CS4 are two very different programs. A flash application running inside a browser even moreso.